# Printing line by line in console from command line

Tags: java

I need to execute command in command line and print it on console.I did it through process Builder.
It is printing batch output.(i.e)It waits for the whole command to finish execution and it prints finally.But I want to print instantly.Every line when printed on command line has to be printed simultaneously in the console.When I try to debug i found it is printing line by line.

```
final BufferedReader m_stdOutput;
            final BufferedReader m_stdError;
            probuilder.directory(new File("C:\\sss"));
            Process m_process = null;
            try {
                        m_process = probuilder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m_stdOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_process.getInputStream()));
                    m_stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_process.getErrorStream()));

                    Thread m_outputThread = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            String line;
                            try {
                                while ((line = m_stdOutput.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(line);
                                }} catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    m_outputThread.start();
                    Thread m_errorThread = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                                String line1;

                            try {
                                while ((line1 =m_stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                                    System.out.println(line1);
                                }} catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    m_errorThread.start();
```

Comment: Try not to use `BufferedReader` and print each character from the `InputStream` itself...

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessBuilder` has a method that eliminate the need for separate threads for the I/O:

```
probuilder.directory(new File("C:\\sss"));
probuilder.inheritIO(); // Added
Process m_process = null;
try {
    m_process = probuilder.start();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `inheritIO` line makes the IO streams for the process the same as the IO streams for the Java program, so you don't need those threads. If you let Java do the work for you, it will work correctly.